How to securely call C++ APIs from a Java application?
I have a C++ library (myLibraryMd.lib/myLibraryMt.lib) and the header file myClass.h that contains the declaration of APIs that are called on the myClass class/object. There are other headers/APIs published too. Call them myClass2.h etc.
I am trying to create a Java application and be able to call these C++ APIs (including instantiating of myClass/myClass2 objects).
I have looked into JNI solution for this, but unsure as to how I could secure the DLLs. I would like to prevent a scenario where the DLL could be swapped out or the APIs spoofed.
I have looked into signing the dll and verifying it's hash (hardcoded into the interface) in the Java interface, however these aren’t fool proof as the Java files can be reconstructed from the Java application and once the hash is determined, it’s game over.
How can I implement a secure solution where I ensure the application calls the right DLLs?
I am part of the team that develops the C++ library/APIs and we publish to application teams. So the security feature would have to be integrated into the interfaces/dll published by our team.

in general - it is impossible, as soon as user has both jar/dll - he can hack everything; any kind of obsuscation/encryption/signing - makes task harder, but not 100% solution

if there was an answer to this question we wouldn't be getting pirated games a week before the game's release date from multi-billion dollar companies. with that in mind, try to not store any sensitive information in those files.

Security just makes things inconvenient. Hopefully more inconvenient for the baddies than for the goodies.

It isn't going to work.  If the user can make a DLL that has the same functions as the real DLL then they can call the original DLL functions from their DLL and they can see/edit the stuff going in and the stuff coming out.  Even if you use an HMAC to prevent editing they just need to find the key in the JAR or DLL - you can decompile both JAva JAR files and C++ DLLs pretty easily.  (Don't ask how I know this...)

Once your code is on the users machine, in whatever form, the user can figure out how it works and abuse it. You can make that harder but you can't make it impossible.

Security by obscurity is the only real security. You can deter would-be attackers by adding sneaky checks that force them to decompile, but anyone capable enough will just decompile and replicate. It unfortunately makes offering ideas really hard since that's itself a security risk.

Removed the Java and JNI tags. This problem applies to any host program loading a DLL. If your threat model starts from "the user can replace any files they want" there is no technological solution.
